# How to use multiple forms to the same model in Odoo 13

Tags: xml, odoo

We trying to use some views(forms type) to the same model, but everytime only apears one of them. Here are our example code:

```
<!--************************************
    Our Actions
 ************************************-->

<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="miinventario.action_vale_salida">
    <field name="res_model">stock.picking</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="view_ids" eval="[(5, 0, 0),
                                  (0, 0, {'view_mode': 'tree', 'view_id': ref('miinventario.tree_valesalida')}),
                                  (0, 0, {'view_mode': 'form', 'view_id': ref('miinventario.form_valesalida')})]"/>
</record>


<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="miinventario.action_recepcion">
    <field name="res_model">stock.picking</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="view_ids" eval="[(5, 0, 0),
                                  (0, 0, {'view_mode': 'tree', 'view_id': ref('miinventario.tree_recepciones')}),
                                  (0, 0, {'view_mode': 'form', 'view_id': ref('miinventario.form_recepciones')})]"/>
</record>

<!--************************************
    Our MenuItems
 ************************************-->

<menuitem id="miinventario.mnu_vale_salida"
    name="Mi opcion 1"
    parent="stock.menu_stock_warehouse_mgmt"
    action="miinventario.action_vale_salida"
/>

<menuitem id="miinventario.mnu_recepcion"
    name="Mi opcion 2"
    parent="stock.menu_stock_warehouse_mgmt"
    action="miinventario.action_recepcion"
/>
```

We need some help. ¿Are there something wrong?

Regards,
Sergio

Answer (score 1):

Create two action's. For Example :-

```
<record id="action_one_id" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Model Name</field>
    <field name="res_model">model.name</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="view_id" eval="False"/>
    <field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
        </p>
    </field>
 </record>

 <record id="action_two_id" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Model Name</field>
    <field name="res_model">model.name</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="view_id" eval="False"/>
    <field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
        </p>
    </field>
 </record>
```

Then create the action's specifying the view_id:

```
<record id="record_tree_id" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
    <field eval="1" name="sequence"/>
    <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="view_id_tree_one"/>
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_one_id"/>
</record>

<record id="record_form_id" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
    <field eval="2" name="sequence"/>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="view_id_form_one"/>
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_one_id"/>
</record>

<record id="record_two_tree_id" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
    <field eval="1" name="sequence"/>
    <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="view_id_two_tree"/>
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_two_id"/>
</record>

<record id="record_two_form_id" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
    <field eval="2" name="sequence"/>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="view_id_one_tree"/>
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_two_id"/>
</record>
```